# iphone video image on load not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone

I display a video on my web page with the following:

```
<div class="gl-bot-left">
    <video controls="">
        <source src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/video.fixgasleaks.mp4" 
                type="video/mp4">Your browserdoes not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
```

This works fine on the desktop.  The video loads and you can see a image of the start.  However, on the iphone I get an image of the play button instead of an actual image.  When I press it the video starts.  Is there a way we can display a image for the video when it's first loaded?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML `<video>` object has a specific attribute for your use-case: `poster`. It specifies an image to be shown while playback of your video didn't start yet.

```html
<div class="gl-bot-left">
    <video controls="" poster="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300">
        <source src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/video.fixgasleaks.mp4" 
                type="video/mp4">Your browserdoes not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
```

## Edit

I really can't tell you why it ain't working on your iOs device but I can offer a nifty workaround.

- add a HTML `<image>` with your desired placeholder image right before the `<video>` tag and group those two inside a `<div>`.
- make the image invisible by setting it's visibility to **hidden**
- create an empty 64x64x (or smaller) empty transparent .png and use it as the **poster** image for the video element. This will make sure it doesn't display the video's first frame.
- finally listen for the loadedMetaData event and inside it's callback function resize the image to the dimensions of the video and set the image's opacity to **visible**

```js
var video = document.querySelector('video');

function metaDataLoaded() {
  var image = document.querySelector('img');
  image.width = video.videoWidth;
  image.height = video.videoHeight;
  image.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```css
.container img {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

video {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="gl-bot-left">
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/2/300/200">
    <video controls="" poster="https://i.imgur.com/A9WPATe.png" onloadedmetadata="metaDataLoaded()">
        <source src="https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/video.fixgasleaks.mp4" 
                type="video/mp4">Your browserdoes not support the video tag.
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so, that works on the desktop but on the iphone I still get just a grey circle with a white triangle inside representing the play button.  When clicked the video plays.  How to get the iphone to display an image on video load?